# Iteratively reveal one html table row after the other upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with a fixed number of rows, of which only the first one is visible from the beginning. Upon clicking a button, row 2 should be revealed. Upon clicking the same button again, row 3 should be revealed, and so on.

Importantly, the full table should be loaded at the beginning (each row contains a specific django formfield), so I do not want to generate additional html rows when clicking the button.
I found lots of stuff on toggling/showing table rows using jQuery, but what I want to do here is I want to show additional rows each time the button is clicked.
My idea was to first initiate and then increment a variable upon clicking in Javascript, and then show an additional row each time. I failed.

I am newbie to Javascript, any suggestions highly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  var $rows = $("#fullTable tr");
  $("RevealRow").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $rows.eq(counter).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fullTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td>Row 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td>Row 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td>Row 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="RevealRow">Show more rows</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#RevealRow").click(function () {
                $("#fullTable tr:visible").next().show();
            });
        });
```

Comment: That's a nice implementation without a counter, thanks!